# Search special-string in a text and replace with contents from array

Tags: php, regex

Consider this text

```
$text = 'bla bla bla bla (=abc) bla bla bla bla (=var.var)';
```

There are 2 special values there `(=abc)` and `(=var.var)`

I need to replace them with values from this array:

```
$array['abc']='word1';
$array['var.var']='word2';
```

Basically inside the pattern is (=[a-z.]+)  (chars a-z and dot).

Result i need: `bla bla bla bla *word1* bla bla bla bla *word2*` (without *)

I tried this with no luck

```
preg_replace('/\(=([a-z\.]+)\)/',"$array['\\1']",$text);
```

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE, expecting T_STRING or T_VARIABLE or T_NUM_STRING in D:\net\test\index.php on line 9

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you the replacement string cannot be derived from the contents of the match (it involves external data in `$array`, you need to use [`preg_replace_callback`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php).

This example assumes PHP 5.3 for anonymous functions, but you can do the same (in a slightly more cumbersome way) with `create_function` in any PHP version.

```
$text = 'bla bla bla bla (=abc) bla bla bla bla (=var.var)';
$array['abc']='word1';
$array['var.var']='word2';

$result = preg_replace_callback(
            '/\(=([a-z\.]+)\)/', 
            function($matches) use($array) { return $array[$matches[1]]; },
            $text);
```

Comment: oh crap. first time i see `use(arg)` what's that O_O

Comment: @yes123: Re `use($arg)`: the variable `$arg` (which must be in scope) becomes available to use inside the anonymous function as well -- otherwise you couldn't access it.

Comment: @jon: isn't that equal to `global $arg;` inside the func? Anyway i use php 5.3 so it's fine

Comment: @yes123: If `$arg` is already a global, it is. But `use` will also work if all this code were inside a function and `$array` was a local variable.

Comment: What do you mean? in this case wasn't this equal? `function($matches)  {global $array; return $array[$matches[1]]; }`

Comment: @yes123: I don't think I can explain it any better. Globals are generally undesirable; `use` allows you to avoid them. If you don't mind having a global, then `use` doesn't offer you anything.

Comment: Hm, maybe i gotcha, generally is better to avoid `global` by using `use()` (if i got that right, tho I don't get why)

Comment: @yes123: Have a look at this question as well: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1557787/are-global-variables-in-php-considered-bad-practice

Comment: in the answer the author doesn't seem to advise against global

Comment: @yes123: Read also the first comment below the answer ;)

Comment: ye, as the OP I use global too and i don't see nothing strange with it xD (I use to globalize my variable that contains all the current config)

Answer (score 2):

The < PHP 5.3 solution :)

```
$text = 'bla bla bla bla (=abc) bla bla bla bla (=var.var)';

$text = preg_replace_callback('/\(=([\w.]+?)\)/', 'processMatches', $text);

function processMatches($matches) {
    $array = array();
    $array['abc']='word1';
    $array['var.var']='word2';
    return isset($array[$matches[1]]) ? $array[$matches[1]] : '';
}

var_dump($text); // string(43) "bla bla bla bla word1 bla bla bla bla word2"
```

[CodePad](http://codepad.org/ai6txsW0).

Comment: This is a fully correct solution as well, but it's not ideal because you must either define `$array` inside `processMatches`, or make it a global. But +1 for the `isset` test.

Comment: @Jon Thanks, it is a shame the matches need to scoped to the callback.